# In Manim, how can I rotate a Mobject and scale it at the same time?

Tags: python, manim

I'm using Manim Community v0.17.2, and I am trying to animate a text growing from its center and rotating 90 degrees at the same time.

```
txt_1 = Text("Hello World!", font_size=76).rotate(PI/2)
self.play(
            Rotate(txt_1, -PI/2),
            GrowFromCenter(txt_1)
        )
```

I expected the text to start vertically and very small (with a scale of 0 to be precise), and then it would rotate 90 degrees to get in a horizontal position and scale until it had a font size of 76. Instead, the only animation that is being played is `GrowFromCenter`. I have tried using alternatives like `Succession` with a lag ratio of 0, but I get the same problem. I have also tried using `Transform` and `animate.rotate`, but the rotation is not done well because instead of rotating the object as a whole, it moves each point of the Mobject to it's destination, creating a weird effect. So it looks like I have no other choice but to use `Rotate` in some way.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the built-in animation `SpinInFromNothing`. See [docs](https://docs.manim.community/en/stable/reference/manim.animation.growing.SpinInFromNothing.html).

```py
class SpinGrowText(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        txt_1 = Text("Hello World!", font_size=76)
        self.play(SpinInFromNothing(txt_1, angle=-90*DEGREES, rate_func = linear, run_time = 2))
        self.wait(2)
```